# Bootstrap textarea out of viewport when change width with transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm facing an odd behaviour with Bootstrap.

When I change the width of a textarea with CSS transition or jQuery animate, it expands out of the viewport until the animation is complete.

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="navbar-text">


              <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <textarea class="form-control"></textarea>
                </div>
              </form>


            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

CSS

```
textarea {
  width:100px;
}
textarea:focus {
  transition: 2s all;
  width:500px;
}
```

Here is a Fiddle for demonstration:
https://jsfiddle.net/hqm9urey/2/

---

I couldn't reproduce it only with float:right:
https://jsfiddle.net/05ba14bs/1/

HTML

```
<div>
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
  float:right;
}
textarea {
  width:100px;
}
textarea:focus {
  transition: 2s all;
  width:500px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Contain it in a parent div and give this parent div a max width and some padding. See JSFiddle for more information:

[No more overflow JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gb2ayz8w/4/)

```
<div style="display: block;" id="rulesformitem" class="formitem">
  <label for="rules" id="ruleslabel">Textarea:</label>
  <div class="textwrapper"><textarea cols="2" rows="10" id="rules"/></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
textarea
{
  width:100%;
}
.textwrapper
{
  position: block;
  margin:5px 0;
  padding:0px 10px;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
textarea:focus { 
  transition: 2s all;
  max-width:100%;
  width: 1000000px;
}
```